# Error en la validacion de usuario java

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

Intento validar el usuario directamente desde la base de datos con java, puedo ingresar, pero si ingreso mal el usuario o la contraseña no me saltan los mensajes de error alguien sabe porque?

String usuario = TextFieldUsuario.getText(), contraseña =TextFiedlContraseña.getText().toString();

```
    Statement st;
    try {
        st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario.Usuario='"
                + usuario + "' AND usuario.contraseña='" + contraseña + "'");
        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rs.getString(1).equals(usuario)) {
                if (rs.getString(3).equals(contraseña)) {
                    if (rs.getString(2).equals("0")) {
                        //ingresa interfaz dueño
                        dispose();
                        InterfazDueño Dueño = new InterfazDueño();
                        Dueño.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        Dueño.setResizable(false);
                        Dueño.setVisible(true);
                    } else {
                        //ingresar interfaz empleado
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "La Contraseña es Incorrecta", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El Usuario ingresado es invalido", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No se puede acceder a la base de datos", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como tienes montado el código:

```
st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario.Usuario='"+ usuario + "' AND usuario.contraseña='" + contraseña + "'");
while (rs.next()) {
```

Si no encuentra nada en la query porque el usuario/contraseña no son conrrectos, ya no entra en el while.

Lo ideal sería validar si recupera algo la query, entonces metes tus validaciones, si no pues muestras ya un msj de error (por ejemplo):

```
if (rs.next()) {
    do {
      //validar resultados query
    } while(rs.next()); //Bueno, do-while o while lo que quieras
} else {
    // No hay datos
}
```

Un saludo!